# Is $R^2$ valid in a nonlinear model?

Tags: r-squared, nonlinear

The question is in the title.

The coefficient of determination or

$
R^2 \equiv 1 - \frac{ss_{res}}{ss_{tot}}
$

is valid in a nonlinear model? Why?

Comment: Why not?  $R^2$ measures the percentage of the variance of the target variable that's "explained" by the model on the right hand side; it doesn't matter what form that model takes.

Comment: Moreover, if nonlinear models are estimated by nonlinear least squares, as is often the case, this measure is more than just descriptive.

Comment: The assumption of $SS_{\text{tot}}=SS_{\text{reg}}+SS_{\text{res}}$ only holds for OLS

Comment: @Sebastian Lehmann Away from OLS, there is no need to get hung up on that view of things. $R^2$ can be defined as the square of the correlation between observed and fitted response. Care is needed, because other definitions won't always give the same numbers, and fitting might not be equivalent to maximizing that $R^2$, but such a wider view is possible and often useful.

Answer (score 2):

In laymans terms, you are calculating the distance between the actual points and the predicted line, which you can do whether or not the line is linear.

You can check it out easily in Excel.  If you're using 2007-2010, enter some x and y data, select it, then:
1. Go to the Insert tab
2. Charts section
3. Scatter chart
4. Select the chart to get the Chart Tools tabs
5. Click on layout
6. Analysis section
7. Click on the trendline drop down
8. Click on "more trendline options" (you can also access this by right clicking on the graph, adding a trendline, and then right clicking on the trendline to format it)

Here, you can display the R-squared and adjust the type of line being added to your data.  Watching your R squared automatically recalculate can help you get idea of what kind of model to use.

P.S. Excel won't calculate R-squared values for lines where it doesn't make sense (ex. moving average trend lines)

Comment: This assumes that the reader has Excel. This is often incorrect for people on many platforms. More interestingly, why do you say that $R^2$ makes no sense for moving average trend lines? $R^2$ as the square of the correlation between data and smooth is perfectly well defined. Whether it is useful or interesting is a different question.