# Confusion about the meaning of unexplained variance in R2 interpretation

Tags: regression, probability, mathematical-statistics, variance, r-squared

I want to think about $R^2$ as (in the context of forecasting with different models):
$$\frac{\text{explained variance}}{\text{total variance}} = 1 - \frac{\text{unexplained variance}}{\text{total variance}} $$

Total variance is calculated using:
$$\text{total variance} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bigg((\bar{y_{i}} - y_{i})^{2} \bigg)$$
, which has the same flavor as variance in probability:
$$ \operatorname{V}(Y) = \operatorname{E} \bigg( \Big(\operatorname{E}(Y) - Y) \Big)^{2} \bigg)$$

Now unexplained variance, which I would expect to be **the variance** (in a probabilistic sense) of the error variable $E = \hat{Y} - Y$ calculated as:
$$\text{unexplained variance} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bigg((\bar{e_{i}} - e_{i})^{2} \bigg)$$

is actually calculated as:

$$\text{unexplained variance} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bigg(e_{i}^{2} \bigg)$$

which is not variance (in a probabilistic sense) then. **I find this confusing. Can someone please help explaining.**

Comment: I think you meant to label the residual variance terms as unexplained variance, rather than total variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $\mathrm{Var}[X] = \mathrm{E}\left[\,\left(X - \mathrm{E}[X]\right)^2\,\right] = \mathrm{E}[X^2] - \mathrm{E}[X]^2$.

For a variable with mean zero, i.e. $\mathrm{E}[X] = 0$, that simplifies to $\mathrm{Var}[X] = \mathrm{E}[X^2]$.  In a linear regression with a constant, the residuals always sum to zero, and hence the expression
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{n} \sum e_i^2
\end{equation*}
is estimating something akin to a variance for the residuals.

For the claim about residuals summing to zero (in regressions that include a constant term), see [Why do residuals in linear regression always sum to zero when an intercept is included?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189584/why-do-residuals-in-linear-regression-always-sum-to-zero-when-an-intercept-is-in).

Comment: So I am guessing this is the reason why sometimes it is said that R2 is applicable only to linear regression models (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79225/is-r2-valid-in-a-nonlinear-model). Would it be correct to say that if we wrote R2 expression without the $\operatorname{E}(E) = 0$ assumption it would still "be the same" identity, but now work for both linear and non-linear models?

Comment: What sort of non-linear models do you have in mind?  Even a linear regression can include non-linear effects (e.g. polynomial terms, log terms, splines), and the residuals will still sum to zero as long as you include a constant.

Comment: Neural Networks, Support Vector Machines, Tree-Based methods.

Comment: The notion of $R^2$ makes sense for regression trees, and the residuals still sum to zero.  I'm less familiar with neural networks and SVMs.